# Does one 1-layer for CNN make a sense?

Tags: neural-network, layer, logistic-regression, convolution

I have a problem given:

```
y = convolution2D(input) + biases
```

Does one layer CovNet make any sense? Is it similar to a logistic regression?

Comment: what is your `y` and `input` here?

Comment: Define "make sense". Indeed you can build a net with only one convolution, and it will somehow converge even with just linear activation, but then it's not a universal function approximator and not quite useful.

Comment: thank you, it gives an answer to my question. I was not sure if 1 layer is practically possible. thank you